# How to check if a control is child of another control? "Control.IsChildOf"

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have 3 panels:

```
<asp:Panel ID="ParentPanel" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="AnnoyingPanel" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="P" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

How can I check if `P` is child of `ParentPanel`? Is there some LINQish way to do it?

Is there some more optimized way than the one I provided? Maybe using Linq?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I end up making a recursive extension method

```
public static bool IsChildOf(this Control c, Control parent)
{
    return ((c.Parent != null && c.Parent == parent) || (c.Parent != null ? c.Parent.IsChildOf(parent) : false));
}
```

Resulting in

```
P.IsChildOf(ParentPanel); // true
ParentPanel.IsChildOf(P); // false
```

Comment: Love it man ... I think that is the best solution you could have!

Comment: This code didn't work for me, although it pointed me in the right direction.
Parent can be null, even if there is a visual parent, for example in a ContentPresenter. Better is to use VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(). You can also use DependencyObject instead of Control to make it a bit more generic.

Code:   var visualParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(c); return visualParent == parent || visualParent.IsChildOf(parent);

Answer (score 1):

You can do that search recursive:

```
Panel topParent = GetTopParent(P);
```

---

```
private Panel GetTopParent(Panel child)
{
    if (child.Parent.GetType() == typeof(Panel))
        return GetTopParent((Panel)child.Parent);
    else return child;
}
```

Comment: What if the parent is not a panel?

Comment: That is gonna get the top parent Panel only. I mean it's not gonna blow up, it will just give you the top parent panel that you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isChildofParent = false;  
foreach (Control ctl in ParentPanel.Controls)  
{  
   if (ctl.Controls.Contains(P))  
   {  
      isChildofParent = true;  
      break;  
   }  
}
```

Comment: This is not a recursive solution, it´ll get only the first set of controls.

Comment: This is not recursive because As mentioned by the post author, He has **3** panels. this is a specific solution to his problem. it's simple and it works.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like:

```
var p = Page.FindControl("ParentPanel") as Panel;

var res = p.Controls.AsQueryable().OfType<Panel>().Any(x => x.ID == "P");
```

(disclaimer: not tested)

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tested this, but should work:

```
bool IsParent(Control child, Control parent)
{
    return child.CliendID.StartsWith(parent.ClientID);
}
```

unless you have `ClientIDMode = Static`

**EDIT:** this one work even id you set the ClientIDMode

```
bool IsParent(Control child, Control parent)
{
    return child.NamingContainer != null && (child.NamingContainer == parent || IsParent(child.NamingContainer, parent));
}
```