# check if button_click event was called

Tags: c#, winforms

My button `pict` let you choose some image. Here is a `click_event` for this button:

```
private void picture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                dlg.Title = "Open Image";
                dlg.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                pict.Add(new Bitmap(dlg.FileName));
            }
        }
    }
```

And I have several same panels with this button. If I don't use `pict` button, then it should load a standart image. How to know in what pannel `Picture_Click` is called and in what don't?(also I want to place a small `PictureBox` near those buttons which were clicked). Standart image![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Check if the panel(s) contain the `object sender`.
[Have a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3893414/3637535).

Comment: didn't quite understand that code in the link

Comment: I'll write an example for you but let me ask this first: You want to know the parent panel of the sender to load the image to the appropriate PictureBox, right?

Comment: Do they have a name that can be searched through `Panel.Controls.Find()`?

Comment: name is "panel" + number. For example: panel1, panel2 etc.

Comment: I mean the name of the pictureboxes, forgot to specify, sorry.

Comment: every panel have its unique name. picturebox in every panel has name " "loaded"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Parent property of sender parameter of event handler, to discover the panel:

```
Control myControl = ((Button)sender).Parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void picture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        dlg.Title = "Open Image";
        dlg.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ((Button)sender).Add(new Bitmap(dlg.FileName));
        }
     }
 }
```

This ought to work just fine.

There, i updated the code, this time hopefully i got it right.

Comment: why myPict.Add(new Bitmap(dlg.FileName))? the name of my button is "pict". Maybe you don't quite understand me. I want to place a small picture near "pict" button to mark that in this panel Image was loaded.

Comment: Is pict a string common to all of your buttons? Also, you just want to place a picture near the button that fired off this event, as i understand now, right?

Comment: yes, is common for all buttons. I don't find it useful to make that button name unique, because the name of its parent is unique("panel"+some number). Yes, you understand right.

Comment: Button class has no Add method though, did i get it wrong again? Is pict a button? I feel so stupid right now.

Comment: I want to place that small image so that when I save all these images in dictionary, I want to know where to load standart image. Standart image I load if any image is not loaded manually. That's why I want to add this control(PictureBox). If there is not a "loaded" PictureBox in a panel, then I should load a standart image. Otherwise, load that image that was choose in OpenFileDialog

Comment: pict is a button. Ok, I gonna rename it to pict_but

Comment: To get the parent of the control, you just have to do `Control.Parent` where Control can either be a PictureBox or a Button or any control.

Comment: It doesn't add the image to a constant control anymore (pict), it now gets the object that fired off the event and adds the image to that.

Comment: it adds the image that I choose in OpenFileDialog. But it must add one same image that marks that image in OpenFileDialog was loaded.

Comment: guy, sorry for misleading you. pict is a list with images. sorry.

Comment: No problem, let me annoy you one more time though: `pict` is a List, you want to place a picture near the BUTTON that fires the `picture_Click` event and your question is how to find the button that fired that event, right?

Comment: listen, I understand that my task gonna be easier. pict is a list. If I fired 'picture_Click' then I add to list the picture that I choose in OpenFiledialog. If I didn't fired that button, then add to list standart image.

Comment: What's the standard image?

Comment: it's name is standart_img

Comment: Saw it. The thing is, you can't check if an event has been fired or not, when it happens it just happens. If you have more than one OpenFileDialog usages over your code and you want to see when the dialog is being used (Either an event or a normal method), that is possible. Is that it?

Comment: I decide to replace list with Dictionary<int,Image>. Question: can I know in  picture_click event, in what panel this click is done? So that I can add image to dictinary with special key number

Comment: Yes you can. Use this (Given that picture_Click can be fired from a Button, if not, just change the casting): `((Button)sender).Parent`. It will return a control which you can cast to `Panel`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answer will help you, but maybe instead of void, you can return something, like an integer.

Maybe store in some database or something, like a flag. If this flag is 0, then you haven´t called this method, if it´s 1, then this method has been called.

Something like:

```
private int picture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                dlg.Title = "Open Image";
                dlg.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";

                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    pict.Add(new Bitmap(dlg.FileName));
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

I hope this help!

Best regards